# How to verify if my copy operation is complete in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

Yesterday, I was leaving some job of copying a directory to run overnight. This morning however, I found the computer had restarted because of Windows Update or something.

I was wondering if there is some way to check if the copy is complete?

One way I guess would be check the last modified time of the copy, and when the system restarted. But I was wondering where to find the time when the system restarted?

I was also wondering if where to find some logging files that have the records. I know Event Viewer, but don't know where to find within it.

Other methods are welcome too.

I also would like to hear suggestions for other ways to accomplish the copy instead of just simple copy and paste.

Answer (score 3):

You could compare the directory size and the number of files in the directory by comparing their properties windows. (Right click the folder -> Properties) It won't tell you if all data was copied properly, but should give you an indication of how far the copy operation has gotten. If it's exactly the same, I think it's safe to say it has been completed.

You could just copy it again, overwriting the copy. When a dialog pops up, saying the file already exists, check "Use action on all" and press "Preserve old file/skip file".

Furthermore, you'll find an entry in your system's logs of when the computer has booted, giving you an indication on when the reboot has occured. (Start -> Right click "Computer" -> "Manage" -> Select "Logs" in the left column -> Select "Custom Views" -> Select the one called "Administrative ..." and look for entries that have "Wininit". That's when Windows was booted.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know there is no integrated function in Windows that will tell you whether the operation completes or not.

For a more involved system you might want to look into 3rd party file explorers.

Check out a small list here:

http://www.simplehelp.net/2006/10/11/10-windows-explorer-alternatives-compared-and-reviewed/

The list is old but most of the programs on it are still viable alternatives in their newest iterations.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to akseli's suggestion, I'd recommend you check out [TeraCopy](http://www.codesector.com/teracopy.php). Some of its features include error recovery and ability to pause and resume file transfers.

Comment: I use this program all the time. Once a copy/move is finished it can show a log with all success/failure of every file operation. So you can find which files you skipped or couldn't be copied.

Answer (score 1):

Another option is Microsoft's [SyncToy](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=c26efa36-98e0-4ee9-a7c5-98d0592d8c52) - that would log the results of the operation, and subsequent syncs could be made to only copy changed or missing files.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Robocopy to copy using the command line.  You can use it in scripts, and there are options to keep the original timestamps and for logging to a text file.

eg.

```
robocopy "%_source%" "%_destination%" /E /ZB /EFSRAW /DCOPY:T /XJ /R:3 /W:10 /V /NP /TEE /XO /XN /LOG+:"%COMMAND%\logs\%COMPUTERNAME%\%USERNAME%\robocopy.log"
```

You can type this to find out when the computer was restarted:

`systeminfo | findstr /i boot`